# multiple amount of asynchronous calls to web service in Silverlight, bind response to request

Tags: silverlight

I want to send multiple asynchronous calls to different web services with silverlight and be able to match the responses to each request.

Lets say i have a list with n items in it. Every item represents a string URL of a web service. So you may have 2 services, but you also may have 7.
Now, i have a GUI and when i press a button, the list with the URLs is iterated and to every service a request is sent. You do not know how many services you might call, so it has to be dynamic.
I have solved the sending part, and i get all the responses, BUT with my solution there is no way to figure out which response refers to which request.

```
private void startCall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var urls = {"http://this.is.the.first/service1", "http://this.is.thesecond/service2", "http://this.is.thethirt/service3"};
          foreach (var item in urls)
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item));               
            }

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                list_ResponseFromServer.Add(e.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In this example i have 3 services/items in the list. And i also get 3 responses to the handler void wc_DownloadStringCompleted, but i do not know in what order.
Its obvious i want to have

```
ListRequest(A,B,C,D,E)

ListResponse(A,B,C,D,E)
```

but i do not know if response A takes much longer than response B,C

so I might get in my `ListResponse(B,C,D,A,E)` => what is FAIL

I have seen some examples with 2 asynchronous calls, but they were all hardcoded. For every request, response they had several hardcoded methods/handlers.
It would be great if someone could help me to solve this problem with a variable amount of multiple asynchronous calls to different webServices

Comment: Looking at some of your comments it seems that you want to ensure that processing of responses occurs in the order in which they were made, is this true?

Comment: hmmm well that would be sneaky ^^. But my fault, i was not clear enough. I do not want the responses to return in the same order, they were requestet. They can return mixed up, but i wanted to be able to order those responses in the end. Not the arrivel order, but how they are stored in the end all ordered in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a delegate to create a capture like this:-

```
private void startCall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var urls = {"http://this.is.the.first/service1", "http://this.is.thesecond/service2", "http://this.is.thethirt/service3"};
    foreach string item in urls)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(item);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
        {
             if (args.Error == null)
             {
                 // You can use the uri variable to determine which Uri this is a response to.
                 // NOTE: don't use item variable here.
                 list_ResponseFromServer.Add(args.Result);
             }
        };             
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item));               
    }
 }
```

**Edit**: Response to comments

By one means or another you need a way to corelate a response to the orignating request.  The Silverlight API offers no built in mechanism to do that, there is no standard solution.  So yes you need to write your own code to relate an asynchronous response to the originating Url if that is important to you.  If you prefer to use the original string url then add another string variable inside the `foreach` code block and assign `item` to it.

What it sounds like you are looking for is away to guarantee the order that the responses arrive in to match the order they are generated.  The only way to do that is to issue each request only when the previous response has arrived.  Whilst that is possible (I've written a series of [blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/category/13068.aspx) on the subject), I wouldn't recommend it as solution in this case.

Comment: First of all, big thx for your answer. Your code is sending requests and responses are stored into list_ResponseFromServer.

Comment: First of all, big thx for your answer. Your code is sending requests and responses are stored into list_ResponseFromServer. Unfortunatly the order of the responses is random.

1) I have now seen that "uri" offers some Properties like AbsolutePath, Query, etc. "uri" contains somewhere the link/url from the service. So in the end i would have to match response with the proper request on my own? Write some business logic and compare var urls(every item) with each uri and asign the response to an index of another list?

2) Is there no pattern or standardsolution to this kind of problem?

Comment: I have 2 of those Blogs in my Favorites saved :), 1 have not thought what to do and how to deal with a sent request into Nirvana. I mean how long do i wait for the response? Maybe the service is down or i used a wrong URL. Can i somehow say: Cancel all NOT responded requests after 10 sec? I am just wondering how to use DispatcherTime or Stopwatch in your DELEGATE/LAMBDA solution to have some kind of controlled timout if a response takes to long. btw, what do u think about the solution from Leo?

Comment: @Gero: 1) thats an entirely new question, you need create a method that can generate the request and in parallel spin up a timer.  This is outside the scope of this current question, ask another with those details.

Comment: Hi Anthony, you are right. I will invest some thoughts about the new question, and if i can not solve, i will create a new question. I might post the link to that question here. If i come up with a solution, i will post solution here too. Big thx to You and Leo. Unfortunatly i can not declare your both answers as correct :/ no rights

Comment: @Gero: Yes its difficult to choose a "correct" answer when you can't separate your current work from the isolated question you've asked.  Both answers work and answer your question, both give you a way to corealate a response to a request.  Mine allows for out of order processing (ordered processing was not a condition of the original question). Leo's supports ordered processing at the expense of delaying the processing the responses hence if response processing represents some significant work would be costly.  Pick the one your most likely to use, they aren't going to improve much from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom object to DownloadStringAsync, so I change a little Anthony code:

```
var urls = {"http://this.is.the.first/service1", "http://this.is.thesecond/service2", "http://this.is.thethirt/service3"};

        var i = 0;
        var maxRequests = urls.Length;

        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();

        foreach (string item in urls)
        {                
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
            {                                        

                if (args.Error == null)
                {                        
                   //add the the caller "id" and the response
                    dict.Add((int)args.UserState, args.Result);    
                }

                //here you test if it is the last request... if it is, you can
                //order the list and use it as you want 
                if (dict.Count == maxRequests)
                {
                    var orderedResults = dict.OrderBy(a => a.Key);                        
                }

            };

            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item), i++);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, on the first view, your code delivers the same order i get with my "ordersolution". I posted an answer. I kinda had the same idea like you, but when i tested "int x=(int)args.UserState; i always got an Exception. Maybe because i did not send the i++

Comment: Exaclty, the UserState is the second parameter of DownloadStringAsync (in this case, i++) - you can pass a custom object there to identify your requests. In the example I pass a sequencial integer so you can order the requests after they all finish (the line "dict.OrderBy(a=>a.Key)" does that... in the end "dict" would contain all responses in order of request :)

Comment: I made several tests with 3-6 service URL and both solutions had the same order, so i guess they are ok. But what happens if dict.Count==maxRequests is never true, because one of the URL is pointing into nirvana and there is no service to replay? Does it make any sense to use a timeout? Is there any uri/wc.timeout=10;? Something like: send requests, wait ONLY 10 sec, order what you have already received and do not care for the rest of the missing responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
           {
            if (uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Equals(urls[i]))
            {
                list_ResponseFromServer.RemoveAt(i);
                list_ResponseFromServer.Insert(i, args.Result);
            }
        }
```

that was my fast hack how to bring responses into same order like the requests. If everything is unique you could use "break;" too